# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined using path.extname

Tags: node.js, cloudinary

I am trying to upload my image from client to back end and store image on cloudinary

I am getting error from backend like this:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
> at dataUri (/Users/nhannguyen/Desktop/Web/server/services/users/usersAPI.js:353:50)
> at /Users/nhannguyen/Desktop/Web/server/services/users/usersAPI.js:358:18

and this is what my console gave me: `sampleLogo.png`

Here is my route code base from back end:

```
router.post('/upload/image', function (req, res, next) {


  const dUri = new Datauri();

  console.log(req.files.file.name);

  const dataUri = (req) => dUri(path.extname(req.name).toString(), req.data);

  if (req.files) {
    const { image } = req.files;

    const file = dataUri(image).content;
   
    cloudinary.uploader.upload(file)
      .then(result => {
      const imageUrl = result.url;
      return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Success', data: { imageUrl } });
    }).catch(err =>  res.status(400).json({message:'Error', data: { err}}));
  } else {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Error' });
  }

});
```

console.log(req):

```
  files: {
    file: {
      name: 'teammateme.png',
      data: <Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 0d 20 00 00 07 23 08 06 00 00 00 fb dd 7b d3 00 00 0c 6a 69 43 43 50 49 43 43 20 50 72 6f 66 69 ... 343642 more bytes>,
      size: 343692,
      encoding: '7bit',
      tempFilePath: '',
      truncated: false,
      mimetype: 'image/png',
      md5: '13ca18cd0cf24d1e955a8c22475e79a0',
      mv: [Function: mv]
    }
  },
```

Comment: did you check `req.name` value? It seems like the problem lies on that line

Comment: What middleware are you using to populate the file objects? Is it something like multer? If so, can you share that config? is it certainly populating the objects as you expect?

Comment: Hey It's happening exactly the very same to me, did you managed to solve it? @Nathan-nguyen ?

Comment: Could you please change this: ```const { image } = req.files;  const file = dataUri(image).content;``` to ```const file = dataUri(req.files.file).content;``` and update with the observation.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to destruct a property `image` on `files` object but the only property available in that object is `file` with correspondent name property so you should replace `image` with `file` like this:

```js
router.post('/upload/image', function (req, res, next) {
// ...
if (req.files) {
    const image = req.files.file;

    const file = dataUri(image).content;
    // ...

  } else {
    // ...
  }
});
```